# MQTT Mosquitto bridging configuration

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to bridge my mosquitto broker running in raspberry pi to the cloud Mosquitto mqtt broker(test.mosquitto.org:1883).

I am not getting message in my client connected to the local broker,  When I publish from a client connected to the cloud broker . But I am getting messages on the client connected to the cloud mosquitto broker from the client connected to the local MQTT Broker. I don't have any firewalls to block messages.

my mosquitto.conf file is like this

```
connection bridge-01
address test.mosquitto.org:1883
topic # out 0
topic # in 0
```

And I also have

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```

in my config

How to solve this issue?. Where am I going wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global wildcard subscriptions (subscribing to `#`) is disabled on the `test.mosquitto.org` broker because it generates too much load.

e.g.

```
$ mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -v -t '#' 
All subscription requests were denied.
```

You can change the `topic # in 0` line to only pull in only the topics you are actually using.

Please also remember this broker is only really meant for testing, you should not be using it as a free cloud relay for anything long term.